# file encryption using simple password

Tags: java, android, encryption, file-io

I am very beginner in java language. I thought of encrypting and decrypting any files in java ( android ) and google a lot.
I found many examples, but none of them were helpful for me. I could not understand them.

I want a very simple example to encrypt a file and then decrypt it later using a password provided by me and not auto generated by the app.

To make it more clear:

```
java.encrypt(file,destination, password );
```

will encrypt a file using password and save in the destination.

```
java.decrypt(file,destination, password);
```

will decrypt the file and save in the destination.

I humbly beg you for the simple example.

Comment: Are you a beginner programmer? Or just a beginner with Java? There’s a huge difference. If you know little of encryption and cryptography, you might want to start there or even somewhere else on your learning quest. If you know little about coding, you need to start somewhere else entirely, as this topic is not for beginners.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried.

Comment: Nevertheless, here’s your simple example: [XOR encryption](https://projecteuler.net/problem=59). It’s a “lowest difficulty” Project Euler question. Note that `^` is the XOR operator in Java.

Comment: I am a beginner programmer.

Comment: But I am intermediate in Droidscript.

Comment: `none of them were helpful for me. I could not understand them` care to elaborate? What would be helpful? What exactly you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple blog [about encryption in Java](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) you could find inspiration there, including password based encryption

Comment: Please add actual content to your answer by quoting at least the most important parts of your blog. Just in case your blog goes offline or is blocked for some users.